# pattern matching the directory contents in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a directory with a list of files and I would like to match the contents of the direcotry with a pattern

```
>>os.listdir(os.getcwd()) gives
[2010.1.1-19999, 2011.1.1-124444]

>> fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(os.getcwd()),"\d+\.\d\.\d\-\d+")
[]
```

The result is null and the fnmatch function does not pattern match the contents of the directory listing.

what is the error here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\d+\.\d\.\d\-\d+"` is not a `fnmatch` globbing pattern, it's a regular expression. From the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html):

> This module provides support for Unix shell-style wildcards, which are *not* the same as regular expressions (which are documented in the `re` module).

If you wanted to use a regular expression, use the `re` module to test your filenames:

```
import re

[filename for filename in os.listdir() if re.match(r"^\d+\.\d\.\d\-\d+$", filename)]
```

As a side note, if you find yourself using `fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(directory), pattern)`, then just use [`glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, pattern))`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) instead.